# Close responsive navigation after clicking navigation item anchor link

Tags: javascript, navigation

I've been having issues on getting my responsive navigation to collapse after clicking on the anchors or when clicking outside out the navigation drop-down. My code snippet doesn't work as expected. You can view my site in another tab and resize the window to a mobile view: 
http://www.jeremyalexander.webhostingforstudents.com/

My responsive navigation closes by default after selecting the hamburger icon or the home anchor. Any suggestions?

```js
function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
            if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
            x.className = "topnav";
            }
            }
```

```css
/*
File Name: navigation.css
Date: 03/23/18
Programmer: Jeremy Alexander
*/

/* MOBILE STYLESHEET */

.topnav {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index:2;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #212414;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.active {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #F0B072;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  .topnav.responsive {position: fixed;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 80px;  
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: fixed;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  }
    
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
    
.topnav a {
    padding: none;
    width: 20%;
}    
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>    
            <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#services">Services</a>
            <a href="#my-work">My Work</a>
            <a href="#about-me">About Me</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        
    </nav>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <main>
        
        <section class="section group" id="services">
            <h2>Services</h2>
            <p>
             Aliquam egestas blandit ultricies. Nullam rhoncus quam ut erat efficitur suscipit. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce neque orci, vehicula a justo sit amet, ultrices pellentesque ex. Integer ac velit purus. Morbi lorem neque, vehicula eget ornare quis, venenatis quis risus. Integer vitae volutpat arcu. Suspendisse malesuada sagittis sem. Phasellus malesuada porttitor velit at dapibus. In porta sit amet diam a tempus.

Phasellus nec erat vitae nulla aliquet cursus vel at urna. Duis tempor ut purus non fringilla. Nam ipsum dui, sollicitudin ut mauris interdum, convallis efficitur velit. Suspendisse vehicula nisi eget libero faucibus aliquam. Sed euismod vel risus at egestas. Nam ornare risus tincidunt libero accumsan elementum. Maecenas mattis eros quis magna vestibulum rhoncus. Donec euismod arcu vitae orci maximus tincidunt. Donec pulvinar ornare facilisis. Aenean volutpat sed nisi non volutpat. In lorem arcu, facilisis quis ante eu, molestie aliquam diam. Aliquam gravida convallis mi, sit amet tempus tortor elementum ac. 
            </p>
        </section>
        
        <section class="section group" id="#my-work">
            <h2>My Work</h2>
                        <p>
             Aliquam egestas blandit ultricies. Nullam rhoncus quam ut erat efficitur suscipit. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce neque orci, vehicula a justo sit amet, ultrices pellentesque ex. Integer ac velit purus. Morbi lorem neque, vehicula eget ornare quis, venenatis quis risus. Integer vitae volutpat arcu. Suspendisse malesuada sagittis sem. Phasellus malesuada porttitor velit at dapibus. In porta sit amet diam a tempus.

Phasellus nec erat vitae nulla aliquet cursus vel at urna. Duis tempor ut purus non fringilla. Nam ipsum dui, sollicitudin ut mauris interdum, convallis efficitur velit. Suspendisse vehicula nisi eget libero faucibus aliquam. Sed euismod vel risus at egestas. Nam ornare risus tincidunt libero accumsan elementum. Maecenas mattis eros quis magna vestibulum rhoncus. Donec euismod arcu vitae orci maximus tincidunt. Donec pulvinar ornare facilisis. Aenean volutpat sed nisi non volutpat. In lorem arcu, facilisis quis ante eu, molestie aliquam diam. Aliquam gravida convallis mi, sit amet tempus tortor elementum ac. 
            </p>
        </section>
        
        <section class="section group" id="#about-me">
            <h2>About Me</h2>
                        <p>
             Aliquam egestas blandit ultricies. Nullam rhoncus quam ut erat efficitur suscipit. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce neque orci, vehicula a justo sit amet, ultrices pellentesque ex. Integer ac velit purus. Morbi lorem neque, vehicula eget ornare quis, venenatis quis risus. Integer vitae volutpat arcu. Suspendisse malesuada sagittis sem. Phasellus malesuada porttitor velit at dapibus. In porta sit amet diam a tempus.

Phasellus nec erat vitae nulla aliquet cursus vel at urna. Duis tempor ut purus non fringilla. Nam ipsum dui, sollicitudin ut mauris interdum, convallis efficitur velit. Suspendisse vehicula nisi eget libero faucibus aliquam. Sed euismod vel risus at egestas. Nam ornare risus tincidunt libero accumsan elementum. Maecenas mattis eros quis magna vestibulum rhoncus. Donec euismod arcu vitae orci maximus tincidunt. Donec pulvinar ornare facilisis. Aenean volutpat sed nisi non volutpat. In lorem arcu, facilisis quis ante eu, molestie aliquam diam. Aliquam gravida convallis mi, sit amet tempus tortor elementum ac. 
            </p>
        </section> 
        
        <section class="section group" id="#contact">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
                        <p>
             Aliquam egestas blandit ultricies. Nullam rhoncus quam ut erat efficitur suscipit. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce neque orci, vehicula a justo sit amet, ultrices pellentesque ex. Integer ac velit purus. Morbi lorem neque, vehicula eget ornare quis, venenatis quis risus. Integer vitae volutpat arcu. Suspendisse malesuada sagittis sem. Phasellus malesuada porttitor velit at dapibus. In porta sit amet diam a tempus.

Phasellus nec erat vitae nulla aliquet cursus vel at urna. Duis tempor ut purus non fringilla. Nam ipsum dui, sollicitudin ut mauris interdum, convallis efficitur velit. Suspendisse vehicula nisi eget libero faucibus aliquam. Sed euismod vel risus at egestas. Nam ornare risus tincidunt libero accumsan elementum. Maecenas mattis eros quis magna vestibulum rhoncus. Donec euismod arcu vitae orci maximus tincidunt. Donec pulvinar ornare facilisis. Aenean volutpat sed nisi non volutpat. In lorem arcu, facilisis quis ante eu, molestie aliquam diam. Aliquam gravida convallis mi, sit amet tempus tortor elementum ac. 
            </p>
        </section>
```

Please help me understand how I can fix this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusout):

> The **focusout** event is fired when an element is about to lose focus.
>   The main difference between this event and **blur** is that the latter
>   doesn't **bubble**

So you can use the `focusout` DOM event to call `myFunction` every time the `nav` loses focus. Just add this line below your `myFunction()` function:

```
document.getElementById('myTopnav').addEventListener("focusout", myFunction);
```